# What am i doing wrong with my jQuery if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I know my html is fine, but how do i make this an if else statement. I want the text to disappear and the text of the button to change, and then reverse by pressing the button again.

Here is my code:

```
    $("#disappearingButton").click(function(){

    if($("#thePara").is(":hidden")){
        $("#thePara").show();
        $("#disappearingButton").html("Click to disappear");
    }else{
        $("#thePara").hide();
        $("#disappearingButton").html("Click to reappear");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!$("#thePara").is(":visible")){
```

Or

```
if ($("#thePara").css("display") == "none"){
```

Comment: @user2489995: did you use is(":hidden") or !is(":visible")? I just updated my answer

Comment: @user2489995: strange, that should work. If it still does not you may try css("display") == "none"

Comment: i solved my problem instead of using hide and show i'll use toggle for now and figure it our later. But for helping i'll make the question count as answered.

Answer (score 0):

try this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunu/ma2zj/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#disappearingButton").click(function(){
        $('#btheParaook').toggle(function(){
            $('#disappearingButton').text('click to appear');
        } );
    });
});
```